# Visual Studio Build in Azure DevOps pipeline errors on Microsoft.NET.Sdk.CrossTargeting.targets

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-2019, .net-standard-2.0

I am in the early stages of migrating my codebase from .NET Framework to .NET Standard.  I am converting some of the foundational projects in my solution to SDK Project types with target frameworks of net462 and netstandard2.0.

All of my applications and services are still .NET Framework.

To clarify, I have a library project targeting both frameworks, and then other library projects (.NET Framework only) that have the multi-target project as a reference, and then applications (.NET Framework only) that reference all of the above.

When I compile my solution in Visual Studio 2019, it compiles just fine.  If I do a manual publish, that also works just fine.  However, when I try to do a PR into Azure DevOps, my CI build pipeline errors with this error:

[error]C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.CrossTargeting.targets(27,5): Error : The 'Publish' target is not supported without specifying a target framework. The current project targets multiple frameworks, please specify the framework for the published application.

Google suggests that, if I were using dotnet -publish, I would need to provide a framework parameter.  However the VSBuild task doesn't seem to support that.

The relevant YAML for my pipeline is:

```
steps:
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Check for Build Errors'
  inputs:
    solution: '$(SolutionName)'
    msbuildArgs: '/target:publish'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
    maximumCpuCount: true
```

And ideas or clarifying questions?

Answer (score 1):

Does specifying the MSBuild argument for the target framework in the `msbuildArgs` give you the results you're looking for?

```
    msbuildArgs: '/target:publish /p:TargetFramework=net462'
```

The [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-msbuild) for the `dotnet msbuild` command indicates the same MSBuild args are supported, and directs you (in a roundabout way ) [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks), where you can see the monikers used for the different target frameworks.

Comment: FYI, same argument would likely hold true for the `DotNetCoreCLI@2` "publish" command (in its `arguments`, i.e.  `arguments: '/p:TargetFramework=net462' ` )

Comment: Adding the TargetFramework argument did not fix the error

Comment: Perhaps it could be that you're publishing against a solution file (`sln`) instead of publishing at the project level (unclear as to what your pipeline's `$(SolutionName)` is referencing).  See issue comment [here](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/9324#issuecomment-430366906)

Comment: I am absolutely publishing against a solution (so that we don't have to change our pipeline every time we add a project to our solution)

Comment: Hmm, bummer but totally get it.  And the [next comment](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/9324#issuecomment-585443797) (from this past February) in the linked issue looks to be similar to your predicament.  I'd suggest adding yourself to that list to see if any traction on a solution (no pun intended) can be made.

Comment: That looks to be for dotnet publish, which isn't the same thing.

Comment: The `/p:TargetFreamework=net48` worked for me in a DevOps pipeline that had references to multi-targeted SDK projects of net48,net6.0 where the MsBuild would error out with the net6.0 SDK not being installed.  However for this Release I only needed the net48 version.  Thank you!